# Getting Rails 3 and Passenger to work on CentOS 6

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

My situation is just like what was described in [Getting Rails 3 and Passenger to work on CentOS 5.4 - Apache Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946426/getting-rails-3-and-passenger-to-work-on-centos-5-4-apache-error)

The minor differences are: I use CentOS 6, ruby 1.9.3, passenger 3.0.19, and things compiled under /usr/local/lib/ruby

I also encountered "Could not start the spawn server: /usr/local/lib/ruby: Permission denied (13)"

As "su apache" gives "This account is currently not available", I changed Apache 2 user/group to use my user/group.  And it still has the above error.  I can also cd to the folders and run ruby.  In fact I can start and run my app using the bundled WEBrick server.

So how do I start using Passenger?

**EDIT:** Supplementary info (my /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_passenger.conf) below

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.s‌​o
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /usr/local/lib/
PassengerSpawnMethod conservative
```

And I have disabled SELinux

Comment: And I have disabled SELinux

Comment: Did you add a virtual host? http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root_2

Comment: No I did not.  Do I have to add a virtual host?  The entire thing is on intranet, the server also has no DNS entry: people just use a static IP.  I only do one thing in this server: serve rails app

Comment: Yes - follow the docs I referenced.

Comment: In fact I cannot add a virtual host.  I cannot control the DNS and have no DNS entries.  If I use <VirtualHost *:80> ServerName 192.168.123.45 ... and when a user gets http : // 192.168.123.45/ the original apache welcome page comes up.

Comment: And since in the documentation, deployment to virtual host is section 4.2, deployment to sub URI is section 4.3; I presume either one of them works